# Cannot build my nativescript application in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

When I am building my app in IOS, It is showing the following errors,

`/platforms/ios/Pods/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareDialog.m:502:9: error: unknown type name 'FBSDKBridgeAPICallbackBlock'; did you mean 'FBSDKBridgeAPIResponseBlock'?`

`/platforms/ios/Pods/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareDialog.m:513:52: error: no visible @interface for 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate' declares the selector 'openBridgeAPIRequest:useSafariViewController:fromViewController:completionBlock:`

I have also updated the pod files but the error remains the same.

Comment: Try setting the Swift version to 4.0 on the POD.

Comment: I am build with nativescript not using swift

Comment: Of course you are, but you still have a POD file and Swift libraries used internally.

Comment: I have checked in pod file. There they are not using swift

Comment: May I know which Facebook plugin you are using?

Comment: nativescript-facebook npm

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update the tns with latest version and update your pod repos if needed with the command **pod repo update**. Then clean your app - remove the ./node_modules, ./hooks and ./platforms folders and try to build the app again.